# How is it that a non-static method in PHP can be invoked as if it were static?

Tags: php, oop

See the following code. I have defined a non-static method called `bar` in class `Foo`. But I am invoking the method as if it were static using the `Foo::bar()` syntax. It works: http://ideone.com/I45zLx.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        echo "hello, world\n";
    }
}

Foo::bar();
?>
```

Why did I not get a fatal error that I am trying to invoke a non-static method as static? Could you please point me to the official PHP documentation which clarifies this point?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php - As for your confusion on the absent fatal error; PHP is a scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get a Fatal here , instead a Strict Standard Notice.

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Foo::bar() should not be called
>   statically

Always enable `error_reporting(-1);` on whichever code you test. You could have seen the above on your output if you had enabled this.

See the doc [`here`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think it will generate warning. May be E_STRICT.

This main reason to define static method is you can not refer any other public member inside static function with $this object.

If you try to use $this inside your static function, you'll get a Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context.

Notion is, static method is about restriction is apply and also how is it handle during program execution.